# Crystal Reports WPF viewer running on RDS causing GDI+ Generic Error

Tags: c#, wpf, crystal-reports, rds

I developed a WPF application that shows CR in their new WPF viewer.  If report has a chart one user is getting a GDI+ Generic error.  In my testing I have yet to get the error. Any ideas what might be causing the error?

The app is running in Windows 2008 R2 with RDS.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Rick

Answer (score 0):

WPF does not initilize GDI+, which may cause this error when accessing some of its functions. You can try initializing GDI+ by opening a Windows Forms window. There are also other ways to do that, but it's the fastest way (I know).

Comment: Sorry for the late response but I just got a hold of the laptop that is having the error.  Before I create report object I show a windows form.  I still get the error.